# Drag editors between windows in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I recently updated my eclipse installation to Juno, and I found a important change I'd like to maintain:

In the Indigo version when I have a file opened and drag it tab between eclipse's windows it just moves to the new window. But in Juno version the attempt results in a floating window with the editor of the file just above the target window.

How can I make do this work in Juno? Is there any option for reverting this or I should install the Indigo version?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in the current version of Eclipse (4.2 / Juno). The aim is to fix it for the 4.3 milestone, according to the tracker:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384308

In the meantime, your options are to revert to Indigo, or just open the file manually in the new window via the file tree.